# shorten a list of integers by sums of contiguous positive or negative numbers

Tags: python, list

I would like to write a function to process a list of integers, best way is to show as an example:

```
input [0,1,2,3, -1,-2,-3, 0,1,2,3, -1,-2,-3] will return [6,-6,6,-6]
```

I have a draft here that will actually work:

```
def group_pos_neg_list(nums):
    p_nums = []

    # to determine if the first element >=0 or <0
    # create pos_combined and neg_combined as a list to check the length in the future
    if nums[0] >= 0:
        pos_combined, neg_combined = [nums[0]], []
    elif nums[0] < 0:
        pos_combined, neg_combined = [], [nums[0]]

    # loop over each element from position 1 to the end
    # accumulate pos num and neg nums and set back to 0 if next element is different
    index = 1
    while index < len(nums):
        if nums[index] >= 0 and nums[index-1] >= 0: # both posivite
            pos_combined.append(nums[index])
            index += 1
        elif nums[index] < 0 and nums[index-1] < 0: # both negative
            neg_combined.append(nums[index])
            index += 1
        else:
            if len(pos_combined) > 0:
                p_nums.append(sum(pos_combined))
                pos_combined, neg_combined = [], [nums[index]]
            elif len(neg_combined) > 0:
                p_nums.append(sum(neg_combined))
                pos_combined, neg_combined = [nums[index]], []
            index += 1

    # finish the last combined group
    if len(pos_combined) > 0:
        p_nums.append(sum(pos_combined))
    elif len(neg_combined) > 0:
        p_nums.append(sum(neg_combined))

    return p_nums
```

But I am not quite happy with it, because it looks a bit complicate.
Especially that there is a repeating part of code:

```
if len(pos_combined) > 0:
    p_nums.append(sum(pos_combined))
    pos_combined, neg_combined = [], [nums[index]]
elif len(neg_combined) > 0:
    p_nums.append(sum(neg_combined))
    pos_combined, neg_combined = [nums[index]], []
```

I have to write this twice as the final group of integers will not be counted in the loop, so an extra step is needed.

Is there anyway to simplify this?

Comment: This can be done pretty easily using `itertools.groupby`. Just add up the runs of positive and negative numbers using a list comprehension.

Comment: @ChristianDean I do know how to use groupby, but I am trying to write it out without wheels

Comment: Is your original list guaranteed to be already sorted. In other words, does it have the structure `[1, 2, 3, -1, -2, -3, ...]`?

Comment: @ChristianDean  No, not sorted. Completely random

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Using `groupby`

No need to make it that complex: we can first `groupby` the signum, and then we can calculate the sum, so:

```
from itertools import groupby

[sum(g) for _, g in groupby(data, lambda x: x >= 0)]
```

This then produces:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> data = [0,1,2,3, -1,-2,-3, 0,1,2,3, -1,-2,-3]
>>> [sum(g) for _, g in groupby(data, lambda x: x >= 0)]
[6, -6, 6, -6]
```

So `groupby` produces tuples with the "key" (the part we calculate with the lambda), and an iterable of the "burst" (a continuous subsequence of elements with the same key). We are only interested in the latter `g`, and then calculate `sum(g)` and add that to the list.

## Custom made algorithm

We can also write our own version, by using:

```
swap_idx = [0]
swap_idx += [i+1 for i, (v1, v2) in enumerate(zip(data, data[1:]))
             if (v1 >= 0) != (v2 >= 0)]
swap_idx.append(None)

our_sums = [sum(data[i:j]) for i, j in zip(swap_idx, swap_idx[1:])]
```

Here we first construct a list `swap_idx` that stores the indices where of the element where the signum changes. So for your sample code that is:

```
>>> swap_idx
[0, 4, 7, 11, None]
```

The `0` and `None` are added by the code explicitly. So now that we identified the points where the sign has changed, we can sum these subsequences together, with `sum(data[i:j])`. We thus use `zip(swap_idx, swap_idx[1:])` to obtain two consecutive indices, and thus we can then sum that slice together.

## More verbose version

The above is not very readable: yes it works, but it requires some reasoning. We can also produce a more verbose version, and make it even more generic, for example:

```
def groupby_aggregate(iterable, key=lambda x: x, aggregate=list):
    itr = iter(iterable)
    nx = next(itr)
    kx = kxcur = key(nx)
    current = [nx]
    try:
        while True:
            nx = next(itr)
            kx = key(nx)
            if kx != kxcur:
                yield aggregate(current)
                current = [nx]
                kxcur = kx
            else:
                current.append(nx)
    except StopIteration:
         yield aggregate(current)
```

We can then use it like:

```
list(groupby_aggregate(data, lambda x: x >= 0, sum))
```

Comment: Thanks! I do know how to use groupby, but what if I want to write my own version?

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755: then you are entirely against the spirit of Python.

Comment: Oh come on @Willem :-) I think the OP just wants to create there own function for practice. If he was writing actually production code, then yes, I'd agree with you.

Comment: I understand the spirit, it is just that I am trying to learn the algorithm here...

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755: I added a version with only vanilla Python.

Comment: in that case you can check how [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) works. Equivalent explicit logic is mentioned in the document with the code

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  Can I ask an additional question? Let's say if I have a project, and I write this function, and it needs `itertools.groupby`. Should I `import itertools` inside the function or outside the function? and Is it guaranteed to be able to run in any python environment? I assume the standard library will be carried by any computer with python installed right?

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755: `itertools` is a standard library, and usually imports are done at the tope of the file, unless for instance you introduce cyclic imports, or there are (very) good reasons not to import the module imidiately.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `itertools.groupby`, utilizing a key to group by all the values greater than or equal to zero:

```
import itertools
s = [0,1,2,3, -1,-2,-3, 0,1,2,3, -1,-2,-3]
new_s = [sum(b) for a, b in itertools.groupby(s, key=lambda x: x >=0)]
```

Output:

```
[6, -6, 6, -6]
```

Comment: Thanks! I do know how to use groupby, but what if I want to write my own version?

Comment: @ChristianDean thank you for pointing that out. Please see my recent edit.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do without any external imports, only using `reduce()`:

```
def same_sign(a, b):
    """Returns True if a and b have the same sign"""
    return (a*b>0) or (a>=0 and b>=0)

l = [0,1,2,3, -1,-2,-3, 0,1,2,3, -1,-2,-3] 
reduce(
    lambda x, y: (x+y if same_sign(x,y) else [x, y]) if not isinstance(x, list) else x[:-1] + [x[-1] + y] if same_sign(x[-1],y) else x + [y],
    l
)
#[6, -6, 6, -6]
```

**Explanation**

This is a bit hard to explain, but I'll try.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) calling `reduce()` will:

> Apply function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of iterable, from left to right

In this case I take two values (x and y) from your list and do the following:

- If x is not a `list`:

  - If x and y have the same sign (product >=0), sum them
  - Otherwise return a list `[x, y]`
- If x is a `list`, only modify the last element of x.

  - If the signs match, add y.
  - Otherwise append a new element to the list x

**Note**

You probably *shouldn't* do it this way because the code is hard to read and understand. I just wanted to show that it was possible.

---

**Update**

A more readable version of the same code above:

```
def same_sign(a, b):
    """Returns True if a and b have the same sign"""
    return (a*b>0) or (a>=0 and b>=0)

l = [0,1,2,3, -1,-2,-3, 0,1,2,3, -1,-2,-3] 
def reducer(x, y):
    if isinstance(x, list):
        if same_sign(x[-1], y):
            return x[:-1] + [x[-1] + y]
        else:
            return x + [y]
    else:
        if same_sign(x, y):
            return x+y
        else:
            return [x, y]
reduce(reducer, l)
#[6, -6, 6, -6]
```

Comment: Thanks, not bad! It is just maybe you can write it in multiple lines....no need to do everything in one line, if it looks too implicitly.

Comment: Hi, I was back to re-look at your codes, I want to point out one thing that you might have overlooked, which I made the same mistake before. When you try to use `x*y>=0` as your condition, you are not counting in a negative number followed by 0. Which means a list input `[0,0,-3,1]` will give you `[-3,1]`, instead of `[0,-3,1]`

Comment: And that is why in my codes, I used the `if` and `elif` condition to put it in a way to make sure that the two continguous element is both positive or both negative or `else`.

Comment: You can check my original codes, that will work, just not so elegantly :(, but still an O(n) algorithm

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755 it gets the correct output for `[0,0,-3,1]`. A better case would be `[1, 1, -2, -2, 0,0,-3,1]` which outputs `[2, -7, 1]` instead of [2, -4, 0, -3, 1]` (which I think is what you wanted). I will update.

Comment: Are you sure? In my IDE, `[0,0,-3,1]` will not output `[0,-3,1]`, but will output `[-3,1]`, and yes, your test case will output `[2,-7,1]` which is not what I wanted.

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755 I made an edit that should handle this edge case. Or you could use `np.sign()`, but that would require an import.

Comment: Thanks a lot! actually, reduce() needs an import now :) (in python 3 it belongs to functools). so we are still relying on wheels, lol